# IBM Worklight 6.0 and Webworks 2.2

Tags: cordova, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 6.0 with Blackberry Webworks 10 2.2 on Mac OS

I packaged a Blackberry Worklight App, and when I launch it it seems that plugins are not loading.

When I reloaded the app, I can see the following errors:

```
GET local:///webresources/default/cordova_plugins.json (404 not found response) [native code]:1
GET local:///chrome/webworks.js (404 not found response) [native code]:1
there was a problem loading webworks.js cordova.js:10740
```

Any idea how to solve this? Any guide to how to use Webworks 10 2.2 with Worklight 6.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with WebWorks SDK 2.x for BlackBerry 10 in Worklight 6.x, try to follow the instructions provided in the following blog post (too long to post here): https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_blackberry10_project_with_webworks_sdk_2_0?lang=en

If it still fails for you, edit the question accordingly with any error you are getting, as well as steps to reproduce.

Comment: Finally, Removing webworks.js script tagand Change worklight/cordova.js in script tag to ../../cordova.js in the main HTML file solved the issue